# Cast IEnumerable<T> to runtime type

Tags: c#

How can achieve something similar to `listOfBaseItems.Cast<Child>()` using a type defined in runtime? e.g.

```
var t = typeof(Child); // the type would be a method argument in my case
var desiredType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
var castedList = Convert.ChangeType(listOfBaseItems, desiredType);
```

I get an exception that the items doesn't implement `IConvertible`. What am I missing?

Comment: `Cast` is just a generic extension method, you can use reflection to call it.

Comment: You're trying to cast a `List<Foo>` to a `List<Bar>`, which *cannot* work. `List<T>` is a class and therefore is invariant. You need to better explain what you're trying to achieve here. See [ask]

Comment: Rather than passing type as an argument, is using a generic method an option `public void Bob<T>()`? Or is the type only known at runtime, not compile time?

Comment: @user9993 Sure, I am using a pub-sub bus where I use the CLR type as topic. Therefore I want to do something like Publish<ChildType>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the cast is legal (e.g. `listOfBaseItems` actually contains child items), then you can invoke `Cast` (which is a generic extension method in the `Enumerable` class) at runtime like this:

```
var result = 
    typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethod("Cast")
        .MakeGenericMethod(t)
        .Invoke(null, new object[] {listOfBaseItems});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed!

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for! Thank you sir!